# UseEffect hook not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following [this example](https://medium.com/@verdi/form-validation-in-react-2019-27bc9e39feac) but using a functional component. My field is controlled throught state and it works with no problem. However, none of my functions that update the state are working:

```
function FormFieldTest() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        username: '',
        usernameValid: false,
        formValid: false,
        errorMsg: {}
    });

    useEffect(()=> {
        validateUsername();
        validateForm();
    },[state.username]);

    const updateUsername = (username) => {
        setState({...state, username: username});
    }

    const validateUsername = () => {
        let username = state.username;
        let usernameValid = true;
        let errorMsg = {...state.errorMsg};

        if(username.length < 3) {
            usernameValid = false;
            errorMsg.username = "Must be at least 3 characters long."
        }
        setState({...state,
            usernameValid: usernameValid,
            errorMsg: errorMsg
        });
    }

    const validateForm = () => {
        const usernameValid = state.usernameValid;

        setState({
            ...state,
            formValid: usernameValid
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <ValidationMessage valid={state.usernameValid} message={state.errorMsg.username} />
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" className="form-field" value={state.username} onChange={(e)=>updateUsername(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FormFieldTest;
```

Both the validateForm and validateUsername are working, except they're not setting the state. How come?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped solve your problem @HuitZiloP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attention:  using setState inside useEffect maybe create an infinite loop, if you update state inside it and re-render run again and the useEffect change the same state again and loop again.

Replace your setState to this change:

```
 setState(state => ({ ...state, username: username }));
```

Comment: It almost works. If I remove de dependency, the state is not updated, and if I leave it, it runs the validation on mount and I get the 3 chars min error even before starting to edit.

Comment: You change the other setState methods to the new setState(state => ({ })); ? @HuitZiloP

Comment: "using setState inside useEffect will create an infinite loop" - This is not true. It will only cause an infinite loop if there is either no dependencies (not even an empty array) and updates state, or the effect updates its dependencies unconditionally.

Comment: Most likely the solution is the second code snippet, while leaving the effect dependencies how they were.

Comment: return the dependency to the condition it was in @HuitZiloP [state.username]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add methods called in `useEffect` to it `dependencies`

Write your functions with `useCallback` hooks as you use them, and wasn't to create new function after every render.

And you must put everything in dependencies which can be changed during the time to have their new values after the change, es they will be memoized

I updated your code and put it here, please check is it what you want?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-grothendieck-y438z?file=/src/App.js