# React Native - Class Component to Functional Component (UseEffect: state undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I need to convert my Class Components code to Functional Hooks Components. I have the Class Components logic below that works. However for me to implement `Context Api` I need to convert it to hooks.

I get `storeList` undefined when I console log it and this error...
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'storeList'.map)`.
Is there a way I can make introduce a `state` inside a UseEffect? Thank you in advance

```
const { data, status } = useQuery('stores', fetchStores)
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)

    const storeList = data

    useEffect(() => {

        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            isSelected = false
            return { ...item }
        })

        setIsSelected({ ...isSelected, array: { ...storeList.array } })

        selectHandler()

    }, [])


    const selectHandler = (ind) => {

        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            if (ind == index) {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
            }
            return { ...item }
        })
        setIsSelected({ ...isSelected, array: { ...storeList.array } })
    }
```

Here is the same code as Class component and it works perfectly

```
async componentDidMount() {

        let array = this.state.storeList.map((item, index) => {
            this.isSelected = false
            return { ...item }
        })
        this.setState({ storeList: array })
    }

    selectionHandler = (ind) => {
        const { storeList } = this.state
        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            if (ind == index) {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
            }
            return { ...item }
        })
        this.setState({ storeList: array })
    }
```

Comment: The real issue is how to introduce `data` from my API inside a `useEffect` and inside a `selectionHandler` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
const { data, status } = useQuery('stores', fetchStores)
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)

    const storeList = data

    useEffect(() => {

        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            isSelected = false
            return { ...item }
        })

        setIsSelected(state => ({ ...state, array: { ...storeList.array } }));

        selectHandler()

    }, [])


    const selectHandler = (ind) => {

        let array = storeList.map((item, index) => {
            if (ind == index) {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
            }
            return { ...item }
        })
        setIsSelected(state => ({ ...state, array: { ...storeList.array } }));
    }
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63522873/10994570

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I am still getting an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'storeList.map')` And when I `console.log(storeList)` It comes back as `undefined`. Can I introduce its state in the useEffect before the function runs sort of like in the class component where `const { storeList } = this.state` ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked!! I hope it can help someone else. Thanks

```
    const { data, status } = useQuery('stores', fetchStores)
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)

    const storeList = data

    useEffect(() => {

        handlerControl()


    }, [])

    const handlerControl = async () => {
        try {
            let array = await storeList.map((item, index) => {
                isSelected = false
                return { ...item }
            })

            setIsSelected(array)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }

    }


    const selectHandler = async (ind) => {

        //alert('pressed')
        try {
            let array = await storeList.map((item, index) => {
                if (ind == index) {
                    item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
                }
                return { ...item }
            })
            setIsSelected(array)
            console.log(index)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
```